# ListView - Incorrect drawing of the selected cell

Tags: listview, winapi

If the ListView uses standard drawing processing, it looks like this:
[image: standard drawing processing]

But, if I process the message **NM_CUSTOMDRAW** and  in **CDDS_SUBITEM || CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT** changing *clrTextBk*, it looks like this:
[image: process the message NM_CUSTOMDRAW]

```
//
if pnm^.code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW then
//
if not TblListViewFieldIsCreate then
begin
//
LPNMLVCD:=LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW(lPrm);

//
  case LPNMLVCD^.nmcd.dwDrawStage of
...

//
CDDS_SUBITEM or CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    begin
//
if ListViewItemSel = LPNMLVCD^.nmcd.dwItemSpec then
      begin
//
if LPNMLVCD^.iSubItem = ListViewSubItemSel then
        begin
//
LPNMLVCD^.clrText:=GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);

//
LPNMLVCD^.clrTextBk:=GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
        end
//
else
        begin
//
LPNMLVCD^.clrText:=0;
//
LPNMLVCD^.clrTextBk:=$d8e9ec;
        end;

//
Result:=CDRF_NEWFONT;

//
Exit;
      end;
    end; 
  end;
end;
```

What I need to do to get the drawing of the selected cell like a standard?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] so that we may help you.

Comment: @JonathanPotter code added.

Comment: So you're not actually doing custom drawing yourself. Interesting, I've not noticed that the control behaves this way. I'd guess that actually doing the drawing yourself might be your only option.

Comment: iirc you need to draw the appropriate rect yourself,  ListView_GetItemRect can return the smaller rectangle that would be used to encompass a selected item.

Comment: @AlexK. thank you. Where I should use ListView_GetItemRect, in CDDS_ITEMPOSTERASE?